# Query to Select Data from 3 Tables when one table doent have a FOREIGN KEY to one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

1. I have three tables (ASSETINFO, VENDORINFO, STATEINFO)
2. I execute the following Query:

   ```
   SELECT t2.TYPE [TYPE], t3.Status [STATUS], t4.COMPANY, T5.STATEID [STATE] 

   FROM ASSETINFO t1 

   INNER Join TYPEINFO t2 on t1.TYPEID = t2.TYPEID
   INNER Join STATUSINFO t3 on t1.STATUSID = t3.STATUSID
   INNER Join VENDORINFO t4 on t1.VENDORID = t4.VENDORID 
   INNER Join VENDORINFO t5 on t1.VENDORID = t5.VENDORID
   ```

And get back the following results:

```
TYPE: NETWORK FIREWALL | STATUS: ASSIGNED | COMPANY: DELL  | STATE: 3
```

I am able to retrieve the COMPANY Name from TABLE VENDORINFO but, I don’t know how to replace the STATEID from table STATEINFO with the value in the STATE column?

[image: Three Tables]

Comment: Include the structure for the  TYPEINFO table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second join of `vendorInfo` is not necessary. Instead join in your `Stateinfo` table:

```
SELECT t2.TYPE [TYPE], t3.Status [STATUS], t4.COMPANY, T5.STATE 

FROM ASSETINFO t1 

INNER Join TYPEINFO t2 on t1.TYPEID = t2.TYPEID
INNER Join STATUSINFO t3 on t1.STATUSID = t3.STATUSID
INNER Join VENDORINFO t4 on t1.VENDORID = t4.VENDORID 
INNER Join stateINFO t5 on t4.State = t5.StateId
```

Then just bring in `State`

Comment: The code gave me an error at first at "INNER Join stateINFO t5 on t4.State = t5.StateId". I changed "t4.State " to "t4.StateID" and it worked! Thank you JNevill for you solution.